# firstChild determined weirdly in XML DOM tree

Tags: php, xml, dom

Can someone tell me why the 1st line below is working, but not the other 4?
For each of the 5 lines below...

1.) To the right ---- I wrote what happened.
  2.) Underneathe -  I wrote what I'd expected to happen.

### PHP

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($str);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->formatOutput = true;


/*1*/ echo $doc->firstChild->nodeValue;  //WORKED - Echoed the whole DOC
          //doc-> comments  
/*2*/ echo $doc->firstChild->firstChild->nodeValue;  //DIDNT WORK
          //doc-> comments ->   post            
/*3*/ echo $doc->firstChild->firstChild->textContent; //DIDNT WORK
          //doc-> comments ->   post        
/*4*/ echo $doc->firstChild->firstChild->nextSibling->nodeValue; //Echoed whole 1st <post>
          //doc-> comments ->   post   -> 2nd post          
/*5*/ echo $doc->firstChild->firstChild->nextSibling->firstChild->nodeValue; //Echoed 1st <post>'s <id>("1").
          //doc-> comments ->   post   -> 2nd post ->  id ("2")
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<comments>
    <post>
        <id>1</id><author>Demetrius</author>
    </post>
    <post>
        <id>2</id><author>Demetrius</author>
    </post>
</comments>
```

The only explanation I can come up with is that I had 'offsetting errors' so that 
(at the respective levels of the tree)...

2.) `firstChild` is really the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` tag, and

3.) `firstChild` functioned as `nextSibling` and then

4.) `nextSibling` functioned as `firstChild`.

But that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in your answer, `firstChild` gets text nodes along with element nodes.

More specifically, when a parser is given the following:

```
<comments>
    <post>
```

…the line break after `<comments>` and the four spaces before `<post>` cause the parser to create a text node, and to make that text node the first child of the `comments` element.

So if you’re using `DomDocument.load` and only want the element nodes, then you need to:

1. Use [`DOMNode.childNodes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) and iterate through the node list returned by that.
2. For each node in the `DOMNode.childNodes` node list, use [DOMNode.nodeType](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodetype) to check the [type of each node](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php).
3. If the node type is `XML_TEXT_NODE`, skip it. If it’s `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`, do something.

Alternately, you could use [SimpleXML](http://SimpleXML), which provides a more convenient API that lets you do, e.g.:

```php
$comments = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
echo $comments->post[0]->id;
echo $comments->post[0]->author;
```

Comment: Wow.   I just figured out how useful `var_dump()` is in PHP, to figure out which properties you can get, or check for (e.g. `nodeType`, as you said).   This totally removes the paralyzing fog that I was in.  Thanks anyhow for spelling it all out for me in your post!

Answer (score 0):

When I type "MMM" after the `<comments>`, but  before the first `<post>`, then lines `/*2*/` and `/*3*/` both echo that `MMM` instead of (as before) nothing.  So apparently THE FIRST CHILD OF THE ROOT NODE IS ITS OWN TEXT-CONTENT.  (Then, `nextSibling` gives me the root's first child-*element*, namely `<post>`.)